# Netbeans Project Panel toggle

Tags: netbeans, ide

Is there any keyboard short cut in netbeans for toggling between project panel.

For example if I'm working on a laptop and sometime I need for space for see the code window and always I have to click on the project's panel to hide it.

Is there any way I can quickly hide and show that left side thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> to maximize the current window (e.g. the code editor).

Alternatively, right click on the editor's tab for the current file and choose "Maximize"

Comment: shift escape is working for everything else but not the code editor.

Comment: @Gagan6167: works for me (using 7.3). If you are using a different version check out the keyboard definition in the options dialog. Maybe it's assigned to a different shortcut.

Comment: Yes it's  the same in documentation as well however I don't know why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> to hide or show your project panel.